# rtx 3070 mobile not working properly in xorg 11 -- dynamic boost not engaging to increase Power Limit, changing resolution black screen, menu lag

Tags: xorg, nvidia, power-management, wayland

Computer Type: laptop, nuc x15, Intel NUC X15 Laptop Kit LAPKC71F Product Specifications

GPU: RTX 3070 max-q

CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-11800H Processor (24M Cache, up to 4.60 GHz) , no overclock

Motherboard: Intel LAPKC71F Motherboard , lastest bios KCTGL 357 0044

RAM: Crucial 16GB ddr4 3200mhz x2, no overclock

PSU: laptop PSU

Operating System & Version: nobara 37 /modified fedora 37, upgraded

GPU Drivers: 525.105.17 linux 64bit, upgraded, gnome

Description of Problem:

the GPU is supposed to have three power limit modes, 80w, 100w and 125w. the extra 25w from 100w comes from dynamic boost. There is a physcal button that controls the power limit modes. And in windows it can also be configured through laptop control software.

I checked that i satisfy all the conditions for dynamic boost and in windows 11 dynamic boost works and i get 125w easily. I cannot get higher than 100w in linux and i tested with 3dmark and rdr2 benchmarks they all throttle the power at 100w. on window the power limit is 125w with firestrike 3dmark. I tried on both xorg 11 and wayland it doesnt work.

When I change the resolution from 25601440 to 19201080 in xorg11, the monitor shows black screen. it is fine under wayland.

When I open toolbar menus for nautilus and preference menu for yum it lags severely or freezes completely in xorg11. Menus from all other apps work fine. in wayland menu bars are mostly fine. sometimes they crash but when i restart the apps they become normal again.

#######

Troubleshooting 1: I have read https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/510.60.02/README/dynamicboost.html

I cannot follow the guide since i only have a nvdia-dbus.conf in /usr/share/dbus-1/system.d folder and i am not sure if its what i should move to /etc/dbus-1/system.d

the contents of .conf.

```
<busconfig>
  <type>system</type>
  <policy context="default">
    <allow own="nvidia.powerd.client"/>
    <allow own="nvidia.powerd.server"/>
    <allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="method_return"/>
    <allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="error"/>
    <allow receive_requested_reply="true" receive_type="method_return"/>
    <allow receive_requested_reply="true" receive_type="error"/>
    <allow send_destination="nvidia.powerd.server"/>
    <allow receive_sender="nvidia.powerd.client"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

the service is running too.

```
$ systemctl --type=service --state=running | grep 'nvidia-powerd.service'

nvidia-powerd.service loaded active running nvidia-powerd service
```

Is the .conf in the wrong place and would adding it to /etc/dbus-1/system.d fix it?

I have also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811621/xrandr-debian-black-screen-when-changing-resolution and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=370633. And I am considering the possibility of either my driver module is not loading or my xorg 11 setup is messed up. However I havent encountered error message like " your gpu is not running hardware accelration" or the like and I am really afraid deleteing xorg.conf will cause major error. So i want to learn more before i proceed.

I expect to learn 1. Why isnt dynamic boost in my system running and how do i enable it to get 125w max power for my gpu. 2. I want to be able to switch resolution in xorg 11, and to not lag or freeze when opening nautilus and yum menus. 3..I want to ensure my driver module is running.